# How can I retrieve messages printed to Eclipse console after closing Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I printed lots of logging messages to the console in Eclipse (Java), but accidentally closed Eclipse. Is there any way to access the text I printed to Eclipse's console?

Comment: not that I know of. all your console sessions are killed when you close eclipse.you will have to run your program again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. But you can write the console output to a file additionally in the future. Just open your run configuration switch to the Common tab and tick "File".

Also you can let eclipse ask you if you really want to close it: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Confirm exit when closing last window

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
It will store the console output to a text file

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("consoleOutput.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

Comment: Eclipse can do this automatically no need for code changes.

Comment: yes ofcource you are right but that will be whole workspace dependent but these lines will be just specific program dependent

Comment: Wrong. You enable file logging in Eclipse per run configuration... Your code isn't just superfluous it even might let ressources leak as you are not closing the stream. Also you might place the code wrong in your code and miss the interesting output, or even more worse deploy this code to the production system.

Comment: The scenario you mentioned are absolutely correct. But it is just a pseudo code or something like that